# WPF list filtering

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to WPF so this is probably an easy question. I have an app that reads some words from a csv file and stores them in a list of strings. What I am trying to do is parametise this list to show the most popular words in my list. So in my UI I want to have a text box which when I enter a number e.g. 5 would filter the original list leaving only the 5 most popular (frequent) words in the new list. Can anyone assist with this final step? Thanks -

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Words = LoadWords(fileList);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Words { get; private set; }

    string[] fileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"Z:\My Documents\", "*.csv");


    private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String[] fileList)
    {

        List<String> words = new List<String>();
        //
        if (fileList.Length == 1)
        {

            try
            {
                foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(fileList[0]))
                {
                    string[] rows = line.Split(',');

                    words.AddRange(rows);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Problem!");
            }

        }

        else
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("Please ensure that you have ONE read file in the source folder.", "Problem!");

        }
        return words;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A LINQ query that groups by the word and orders by the count of that word descending should do it. Try this

```
private static IEnumerable<string> GetTopWords(int Count)
{
    var popularWords = (from w in words                
          group w by w
          into grp
          orderby grp.Count() descending
          select grp.Key).Take(Count).ToList();
    return popularWords;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(viewModel.Words)`, which returns `ICollectionView`.

`ICollectionView` exposes `Filter` property of type `Predicate<object>`, that you could involve for filtering.

So the common scenario looks like:

1. ViewModel exposes property PopularCount, that is binded to some textbox in View.
2. ViewModel listens for PopularCount property's changing.
3. When notification occured, model obtains ICollectionView for viewModel.Words collection and set up Filter property.

You could find working sample of Filter property usage [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862511/restricting-wpf-combobox-choices-from-a-known-list/). If you get stuck with code, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if grouping and ordering of the 'words' list is what you want but if yes this could be a way of doing it:

```
    int topN = 3;
    List<string> topNWords = new List<string>();

    string[] words = new string[] {
        "word5",
        "word1",
        "word1",
        "word1",
        "word2",
        "word2",
        "word2",
        "word3",
        "word3",
        "word4",
        "word5",
        "word6",
    };

    // [linq query][1] 
    var wordGroups = from s in words
                       group s by s into g
                       select new { Count = g.Count(), Word = g.Key };

    for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(topN, wordGroups.Count()); i++)
    {
        // (g) => g.Count is a [lambda expression][2]
        // .OrderBy and Reverse are IEnumerable extension methods
        var element = wordGroups.OrderBy((g) => g.Count).Reverse().ElementAt(i);
        topNWords.Add(element.Count + " - " + element.Word);
    }
```

Thsi could be made much shorter by using ordering in the [linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746) select clause but I wished to introduce you to inline [lambdas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) and ienumerable extensions too.

The short version could be:

```
topNWords = (from s in words                
          group s by s
          into g
          orderby g.Count() descending
          select g.Key).Take(Math.Min(topN, g.Count()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading all the words into the list and then sorting it based on the frequency, a cleaner approach would be to create a custom class `MyWord` that stores the word and the frequency. While reading the file, the frequency of the word can be incremented. The class can implement `IComparable<T>` to compare the words based on the frequency.

```
public class MyWord : IComparable<MyWord>
{
    public MyWord(string word)
    {
        this.Word = word;
        this.Frequency = 0;
    }

    public MyWord(string word, int frequency)
    {
        this.Word = word;
        this.Frequency = frequency;
    }

    public string Word { get; private set;}        
    public int Frequency { get; private set;}

    public void IncrementFrequency()
    {
        this.Frequency++;
    }

    public void DecrementFrequency()
    {
        this.Frequency--;
    }

    public int CompareTo(MyWord secondWord)
    {
        return this.Frequency.CompareTo(secondWord.Frequency);
    }
}
```

The main class `VM` would have these members,

```
public IEnumerable<MyWord> Words { get; private set; }

private void ShowMostPopularWords(int numberOfWords)
{
    SortMyWordsDescending();
    listBox1.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords; i++ )
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(this.Words.ElementAt(i).Word + "|" + this.Words.ElementAt(i).Frequency);
    }
}
```

And the call to `ShowMostPopularWords()`

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    int numberOfWords;
    if(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, NumberStyles.Integer, CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, out numberOfWords))
    {
        ShowMostPopularWords(numberOfWords);
    }
}
```